# Angular 5 - Can't Pass Data to Modal

Tags: modal-dialog, angular5, ng-bootstrap, pass-data

**Short summary of what i actually want to do.

 If i click on the heroes table. I need to pass the heroes data from the row clicked to a Modal.**

I read that there are two ways to get Data into a Modal. (NGMODAL)
With @Input and @Output or through a shared Service.
But it doesn't matter which way I am using. The modal opens (and fetches data) always before the data is passed.

I've simply got a table in which all my heroes are displayed.

On a Click on the delete button in a table row I wan't to open the modal and pass the data from my table row. (I want to pass the whole hero, but shouldn't be a difference to just passing the name of the hero).

After that i want to show.
Do you really want to delete hero with name...?
[Cancel], [Yes, Delete] . Onclick on the Yes, Delete Button I want to delete the hero.

**At the moment I can't even display the heroes name I want to delete**

I hope anyone can tell my what I can do and how.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

Shows my Heroes: hero.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Heroes</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Suchbegriff eingeben" class="form-control has-float-label" [(ngModel)]="filter" >
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="heroes">
      <table class="heroes table table-hover table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes | filter:filter:'name':'name'">                  
              <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
```

// I could use (click)="pusHero(hero)" and open the modal afterwars. Than i would get the right data through input. But when i click to open the modal first there is no data, or the data from the row clicked before

```
       <td>
            <ngbd-modal-component (click)="selectRow(hero) [(delhero)]="delhero""></ngbd-modal-component>  </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

heroes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation , Input , EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../../model/hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response } from '@angular/http/src/static_response';
// For use of map
import 'rxjs/Rx';
// Für Pipe und Suche in Liste
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterPipe } from '../../pipes/filter.pipe';

// Component Decorator imported from Component
@Component({
  // Unique Selector
  selector: 'app-hero',
  // URL of Template
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  // URL of stylesheet
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
  hero: Hero;
  filter = '';

  // Is Input for Child Component. In this case modal
  delhero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    // Modal Service
    // private modalService: NgbModal,
    // private ngbdModalComponent: NgbdModalComponent,
    // private ngbdModalContent: NgbdModalContent,
    ) {
    // this.searchableList = ['name','age']  
   }


  selectRow(hero): void {
    console.log("Select the tables data");  
    console.log(hero);
    this.heroService.selectRow(hero);
  }
}
```

Hero Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Hero } from '../model/hero';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http/src/static_response';
// For use of map
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { headersToString } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  )
};

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private hero: Hero;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }


  selectRow(input){
    this.hero = input;
  }

  getRow(){
    console.log(this.hero);
    return this.hero;
  }
}
```

My Modal

modal.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs more" (click)="open()"> <span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
```

modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, SimpleChange, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdModalContent } from './modal.content.component';
import { Hero } from '../../model/hero';
import { HeroService } from '../../hero/hero.service';

// Modal Component
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})

export class NgbdModalComponent {
  // @Input() delhero: Hero;
  // hero: Hero;
  // @Output() getDeleteHero = new EventEmitter();
  name = '';
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
  private heroService: HeroService) {}
  ngOnInit(){
    // this.open();
    // console.log(this.delhero);
  }
  open() {
    var name = this.heroService.getRow();
    // this.getDeleteHero.emit();
    console.log("Modal Component hero");
    // console.log(this.delhero);
    this.name = this.heroService.getRow().name;
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = name;
  }
  delete(){
    console.log("Delete Hero through Hero Service");
  }
}
```

modal.content.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header ">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Hero?</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Delete Hero with Name: {{name}}?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">No, do not delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ja, löschen</button>
      </div>
```

modal.content.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HeroService } from '../../hero/hero.service';
import { Hero } from '../../model/hero';
// Modal Content
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  templateUrl: './modal.content.component.html'
//   styleUrls: ['./modal.content.component.css']
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
//   @Input() Hero;
name = "";
  constructor(
      public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
      privateheroService: HeroService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
        //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
        console.log("NG On Init ModalsContent");
        this.name = this.heroService.getRow().name;
        console.log(this.name);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I found this after having the same problem.
I ended up with working code. Sorry it's not your code but I was having trouble following it. I had to set a variable and pass it in via the click code:

```
    HTML:

<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Option Entry</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-form-label" for="optDescription">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" ngModel id="optDescription" [(ngModel)]="editOption">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Update</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<div *ngIf='optionList && optionList.length'>
  <div *ngFor='let opt of optionList'>

    <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" class="accordianheading">
      <ngb-panel>
        <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
          <span>{{opt.description}}</span>
          <button class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btnline pull-right' (click)='$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation(); editItem(content, opt)'>Edit</button>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
          <js-option-lists [OptionListID]=opt.id></js-option-lists>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>

  </div>
</div>
```

and:

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IOptionListHeader } from '../dtos/option-list-header';
import { OptionListService } from '../services/felixApi/option-list.service';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgModel, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'js-option-lists',
  templateUrl: './option-lists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./option-lists.component.css']
})
export class OptionListsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() OptionListID: number;
  errorMessage: any;
  optionList: IOptionListHeader[] = [];
  updatedOption: any;
  closeResult: string;
  editOption = '';

  constructor(private _optionListService: OptionListService, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  // for now read in all options but will need to read by level
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChildren(this.OptionListID);
  }

  getChildren (id) {
    this._optionListService.getOptionListChildren(id)
    .subscribe(
      optionList => {
        this.optionList = optionList;
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  // Patch change
  patchOrderNo(updatedOption: any) {
     this._optionListService.updateOption(updatedOption).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.getChildren(this.OptionListID);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('error code ' + err.status);
        }
      );
  }

  editItem(content, opt: IOptionListHeader) {
    this.editOption = opt.description;
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
      this.updatedOption = { id: opt.id, description: this.editOption };
      this.patchOrderNo(this.updatedOption);
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
      console.log('cancelled');
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```